# R/Shiny - How can I make the sheet name automatically fill in a field after upload?

Tags: r, excel, shiny

With the outputs I can upload a spreadsheet and use the filename as a reference for some functions in my application. However, I can't "transport" this name to the "checkboxGroupInput" function (where it says "Sheet_Name"). How could I make the sheet name auto-fill in the field after upload? Thanks.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shinyWidgets)
    
    library(readxl)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(readxl)
    library(stringr)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      br(),
      
      fileInput("archive", "Upload file", accept = c(
        ".xlsx")),
      
      textOutput("my_archive"),
      
      # Itens Selection
      
      checkboxGroupInput("additem", "Select Items", names(BancoEA))
    )
    
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      
      # Upload Data Sheet
      
      csv <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$archive
        if (is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)
        df<- read.xlsx(inFile$datapath, header=T)
        return(df)
      })
      
      # Remove Extension Name
      
      output$my_archive <- renderText({
        # Test if file is selected
        if (!is.null(input$x$datapath)) {
          return(sub(".xlsx$", "", basename(input$archive$name)))
        } else {
          return(NULL)
        }
      })
      
      
    }
    
    # App
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: maybe you need to use [`updateCheckboxGroupInput()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/updateCheckboxGroupInput.html) in the server function.

Comment: When I put in the script the name of the spreadsheet loaded in r it shows the names of the items with the checkboxes, but I can't make the file name be transported to the "names( )" function (so that the column labels of the spreadsheet uploaded in checkbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arashHaratian pointed out, you can use `updateChecGroupInput()` inside an observer to update the choices based on the uploaded file.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(stringr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    br(),
    fileInput("archive", "Upload file", accept = c(
        ".xlsx")),
    #textOutput("my_archive"),
    # Itens Selection
    checkboxGroupInput("additem", "Select Items", choices = NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Upload Data Sheet
    
    csv <- reactive({
        req(input$archive)
        inFile <- input$archive
        df <- read_xlsx(inFile$datapath)
        return(df)
    })
    
    #reactive value that will hold the name of the file
    reactive_my_path <- reactive({
        # Test if file is selected
        req(input$archive)
        return(sub(".xlsx$", "", basename(input$archive$name)))
    })
    
    # output$my_archive <- renderText({
    #     reactive_my_path()
    # })
    
    observe({
        input$archive
        #update the choices in input$additem
        updateCheckboxGroupButtons(session,
                                   "additem",
                                   paste('Column names in:', reactive_my_path()),
                                   choices = names(csv()))
    })
}

# App

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another solution would be to directly render the input with `renderUI` inside the server and `uiOutput` inside the ui.

Comment: Almost that, now I just need the sheet label names to be selectable. The sheet name is selectable, but I need the column names to be selectable.

Comment: @JVicM, now the name of the file is the label of the input  and the column names  are the choices to select.

Comment: Now it worked, I had written an error in one of the lines of my code.